# timeout in javascript showing one div straight away and another after 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript

ok so im using timeout to try and get this javascript load after a 3 second delay.

there's two divs being loaded through this javascript;

dialog and cover.

At the moment though the dialog is showing straight away on page load and only the cover is waiting 3 seconds to load/show. but this shouldnt be the case i want both divs to show together after 3 seconds.

Please can someone show me where to fix this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function () {
    var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
    var dlg = document.getElementById("dialog")
    cvr.style.display = "block"
    dlg.style.display = "block"
    if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
        cvr.style.width = "1024"
        cvr.style.height = "100&#37;"
    }
}, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: your code is not nice at all o.O, what are you trying to do??? to hide an element use `display:none` and what is this: `100&#37`??

Answer (score 2):

The reason could be, dialog may be having display:block property at the load time. Try change that to 'none' at the very first through css. Another thing is gave a look at that if statement, you are assigning rather than comparing.u shd be using this '==' operator right.. ?

Cheers .. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your "dlg" element must not be hidden on page load. Check your HTML and CSS, and add `display:none` as needed.